# Adding elements to a simple link-list that contains custom data types

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm starting to abuse this site, but it's really hard to find examples for my kind of problem (everything is class related and I can't use that for this project).

I must simulate a dynamic vector so I thought that I simple link list would be a good way to do that.

```
typedef struct OList{
    Offer element;
    struct OList *next;
}OList;
```

Offer is

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char destination[32];
    char type[32];
    int price;
}Offer;
```

I'm trying to add elements at the beginning of the list

```
OList insertElement(OList *start, Offer of)
{
    OList *temp = (OList*)malloc(sizeof(OList));
    temp->element = of;
    temp->next = start;
    start = temp;
    return *start; 
}
```

Where I'm calling it:

```
OList *start = (OList*)malloc(sizeof(OList));
start->next = NULL;
start = insertElement(start, of);
```

I'm thinking that I should return the first element because I change it with each element I add, but I get the following error:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct OList *' from type
>   'OList'  start = insertElement(start, of);

I came to this conclusion because if I don't return it and I try to go through the list I can access only the element I first declared.

I'm on the point of giving up, but at the same time I really want to understand this.

Comment: 1) `insertElement` should return a pointer. 2) "it's really hard to find examples for my kind of problem" - i'm calling bullshit. it's a simple linked list in C, there are probably thousands of examples (on this site alone!)

Comment: Also, avoid returning pointers of local variables, as they will be invalid once they leave the function.

Comment: @RyanJ I dont see a return of a pointer to a stack variable, where is it?

Comment: My comment was designed to add caution for when the user takes the advice of the first commenter. Right now, there's no pointer being returned at all, so in this case, my comment does not apply.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: you call it bullshit, all simple linked lists related stuff deal with programs who are written in one file, mostly all the code in the main function. Nothing like functions that return pointers. Also, thanks.

Comment: @RyanJ: I'll make sure to not forget this :)

Comment: 1) whether it's one file or not is not related - it's orthogonal to the other problem. perhaps you should start with that subtask and understand how compilation units and header files work... 2) "Nothing like functions that return pointers" - see? bullshit. just click on the related questions on this page. the system even showed you them before you submitted the question. please take some effort.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath: trust me, I read more than I write on this site. If there's no need to ask a question I don't ask it.

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean there hasn't been a similar problem reported, like Karoly is saying. Many people have run into problems similar to yours, all it is is in how much time you spend looking for the solution. Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754986/returning-pointer-from-a-function

Comment: @user3002428: I don't trust you. I will once you say the truth. For now, browse the related question. And learn to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `insertElement` returns `OList` and `start` is of type `OList *`.

You probably want this:

```
OList *insertElement(OList *start, Offer of)
{
    OList *temp = (OList*)malloc(sizeof(OList));
    temp->element = of;
    temp->next = start;
    return temp;
}
```

Also, `OList` is a struct and structs are potentially heavy, while `OList *` takes the same amount of memory an `int` does. So don't blow your stack - pass pointers instead of structs!