# Return pointer from a function without defining the variable as static?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* func();
int main(void) {

int *b = NULL,i;
b = func();
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",*b);
    b++;
}
}

int * func()
{
    int *p;
     p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 7);
     int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; //without using static
     p = arr;
    return p;
}
```

How to return the address of the array to the main function for printing the values ?? Without declaring the array as static if we allocate memory for the array in heap then can we able to pass the array to the function as a pointer ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but not quite there.

The following expressing causes p to point to arr's address **which is not the intended effect**:

```
p = arr;
```

Remember, p is a pointer, and if you do not use the dereference operator *, then you are refering to the pointer's *address* rather than its *value*. arr's memory is deallocated when the function exits, and the memory malloc'd to p is ***lost*** because you reassigned the *address* of p to *point* to the *address* of the *local* variable arr.

The solution is to *copy* the *values* of arr to p using a for loop:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < 7; ++i) {
  p[i] = arr[i];
}
```

This will print the desired result because you replaced the *values* of what p *pointed* to rather than the *address* of p itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The array is gone when you leave the function, any pointer to the array would have an undeterminate value when you leave the function, and using such a pointer in any way invokes undefined behaviour.

Your malloc () call is pointless and leads to a memory leak, because you allocate space for 7 ints on the heap, and then overwrite the pointer, so the memory can never be used or freed.

Comment: But when i referred for passing a variable from a function then they done it by allocating memory for it instead of making it as static.                                                          int *fun()
{
    int *point = malloc(sizeof *point); 
    *point=12;  
    return point;
}                                                                                                         [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754986/returning-pointer-from-a-function)

Comment: @GaneshNagendran, then you have to copy the static array elements to the recently allocated buffer, as recommended in one of the answers.