# Returning string pointer got wrong string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, return

I'm trying to convert decimal to binary. I'm working on function "const char * dtb_16(float a)".
in this function, I'm returning the pointer of the string as code below.

[image: code segment]

OR

```
const char* dtb_16(float a) {
    char str[17];
    int i = 0;;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        a = a * 2;
        if (a > 1) {
            a = a - 1;
            str[i] = '1';
        }
        else
            str[i] = '0';
    }
    str[16] = 0;
    printf("%s \n", str);;
    return str;
}
```

and at main

```
printf("test : %s\n", dtb_16(decimal));
```

the result is something like this:

```
starting read files
Please enter binary bit length: 16
0011101011100001
test : 烫烫眺?
1011110101110000
test : 烫烫眺?
1110001111010111
test : 烫烫眺?
1101110000101000
test : 烫烫眺?
1001100110011001
```

---

the string looks fine in the function `dtb_16`
but it goes wrong when back to main.
I tried return `*str` and `&str`, none of them works.

Comment: Don't return strings from a function that have been defined local to that function.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code but post code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Don't use screenshots to share code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning pointer from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754986/returning-pointer-from-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return an address of a local variable, instead you will have to create the `str` variable on the heap. You can do that by swapping `char str[17];` to `char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 17);`

Comment: That's one possibility, but you should mention that the string needs to be freed at some point.