# why do some function names in C start with *

Tags: c, function, pointers, return-value

for example:

`struct entry *addentry (Struct entry *listPtr, int value){ }`

why does the name have a *

I tried to understand but couldnt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754986/returning-this-pointer-from-a-function

Comment: No C function name starts with or includes a `*` character.  In your example, that character is part of the function's return type: `struct entry *`.

Comment: @ChristiFati You've linked to the wrong question. :)

Comment: In this case, it means the function `addentry` returns a pointer to `struct entry` (`struct entry *`).

Answer (score 2):

The `*` is not part of the function name. It signifies the return value of the function, which is in this case a pointer (because of the object-of `*` operator) to `struct entry`.

It can be written as any of the following:

```
1) struct entry *function(...)

2) struct entry* function (...) 

3) struct entry * function (...)
```

Which one you use is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo in the first parameter declaration. Instead of

```
Struct entry *listPtr
```

there must be

```
struct entry *listPtr
^^^^^^
```

The confusion is due to the placement of the symbol `*` in the declaration

```
struct entry *addentry (struct entry *listPtr, int value){ }
```

Actually the following function declarations are equivalent

```
struct entry *addentry (struct entry *listPtr, int value){ }
struct entry * addentry (struct entry *listPtr, int value){ }
struct entry* addentry (struct entry *listPtr, int value){ }
```

In all the function declarations the function name is `addentry` and the function return type is the pointer type `struct entry *`.

You could even declare the function like

```
struct entry * ( addentry (struct entry *listPtr, int value) ){ }
```

It seems the function adds a new value to a list and returns the possibly updated pointer `listPtr` within the function to the caller.